# Parent Div smaller than child elements contained within

Tags: html, css

I have a container (called `#thumbs`) and within that 4 child containers (`.preview`) and within them 2 images displayed inline.

I am trying to place a border around `.preview`. However, that container is shorter than the images themselves and I cannot figure out how to make them the same height.

Please see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jayden/7Uy2v/

```css
 #thumbs .preview {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#thumbs .preview img {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbs">
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note the images are just temp placeholders for this question as image names are dynamically  generated by our system.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change to `display:inline-block`  instead of `display:inline`

```css
 #thumbs .preview {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block; /* Change */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#thumbs .preview img {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbs">
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1001435/3316/i/950/depositphotos_33165059-Happy-Person-in-the-field.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Uy2v/1/)

Comment: @downvoter care to explain? some one is really envious!

Comment: Would always be the most obvious! Thanks